# Receiving notification from a server thought parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications

I'm developing an app which uses push notification. This notification are sent by a server connected with parse. The application should work as following:

1. The publisher create a news on a web site
2. When he press on the button "publish", he send to the device who has the app an push notification
3. The target devices receive the notification

I looked at the Apple Documentation to find the correct payload for a push notification and the person who developed the server created a JSON which this specification.
He saw that the flow is correct, so when someone press on "publish", he saw that the server generate correctly the notification, but the notification doesn't reach the devices.
When I copy the payload and I generate the notification by parse website the devices receive the notification without any problems. Why when he generate the notification by our server the notification doesn't work and why when we generate the notification by the parse website it works?

I looked on the notification history on parse web site and it's the following:

[image]

the first and the second notification are sent by using our server (API icon) and the 3 is sent by using the parse website, when I put the mouse over "target" column it shows me this:

[image]

I add below my code to register my app to remote notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

So I wanted to ask you, why I can't get the notification when I send them from our server? Why I can get the notification when I send them from parse website?
What's wrong?

Thank you

**PAYLOAD**

```
{
    "id": "",
    "date": "01/01/2015",
    "groups": [17321],
    "contacts": [16902,10402],
    "media": {
        "type": "image",
        "thumb": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200",
        "thumb_low": "",
        "thumb_ori": "",
        "target": "http://lorempixel.com/800/400",
        "targetOn": 1
    },
    "alert": "titolo",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": "1",
    "text": "\n<p>testo <strong>testo bold</strong> <a href=\"http://www.google.it\" target=\"_blank\">link</a></p>",
    "buttons": [{
        "text": "Pulsante 2",
        "url": "http://www.apple.com"
    }, {
        "text": "Pulsante 1",
        "url": "http://www.google.it"
    }],
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
    "notificationType": "push",
    "breakingNews": 1,
    "suggested": 0
}
```

Comment: Are you using rest API?

Comment: Yes we are using rest API (sorry for delay)

Comment: Please share your payload, that may be where the issue lays

Comment: Payload added, try to look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things. You haven't set a device type in your payload. And you also haven't registered the user to a channel when didRegisterForRemoteNotifications is called. These methods aren't mandatory, but it may correct your issue.

```
...
[PFPush storeDeviceToken:newDeviceToken] 
[PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@"global" target:self selector@selector(subscribeFinished:error:)];
}
```

Then include the target channel in your payload.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but yesterday we looked better at the server code and we find an error: the server doesn't select correctly the channel because there was a silly error. Now we fixed it and notification is working from server.